# Batch MySQL if else statement

Tags: mysql, batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to create a batch script that will create a database when executed. If the database is already existing, the script should echo that it already exists. I have it working on Linux, but it's apparently much more different on Windows.

Here is the script:

```
@echo off
SET dbname=1234
SET user=1234
SET password=1234
SET hostinfo=test3
SET RESULT="mysql -u root -ppassword --skip-column-names -e SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%dbname%'"

if %RESULT% == "%dbname%" (
    echo "The database already exists. You can use the reinstall function instead."
) else (
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "CREATE USER '%user%'@'%%'"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "SET PASSWORD FOR '%user%'@'%%' = PASSWORD('%password%')"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO '%user%'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `%dbname%`"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%dbname%` . * TO '%user%'@'%%'"

    echo A new MySQL database has been created for you.
    echo Username: %user%
    echo Password: %password%
    echo Database: %dbname%
    echo Host: %hostinfo%:3306
)
```

The output is just the following:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for '1234'@'%'
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
A new MySQL database has been created for you.
Username: 1234
Password: 1234
Database: 1234
Host: test3:3306
```

How would I do this? It doesn't seem like the if else statement is working correctly...

Kind regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

please before if statement 'echo %RESULT% and %dbname%' it will help you to know why this problem happens

I'm suggesting to change the if to be if "%RESULT%" == "%dbname%"
The result variable include the string for the command but not executed .. so you have to execute it and set the out put into it.
Check this:

```
@echo off
SET dbname=1234
SET user=1234
SET password=1234
SET hostinfo=test3
SET RESULT="mysql -u root -ppassword --skip-column-names -e SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%dbname%'"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('%RESULT%') do set RESULT=%%i

if %RESULT% == "%dbname%" (
    echo "The database already exists. You can use the reinstall function instead."
) else (
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "CREATE USER '%user%'@'%%'"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "SET PASSWORD FOR '%user%'@'%%' = PASSWORD('%password%')"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO '%user%'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `%dbname%`"
    mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%dbname%` . * TO '%user%'@'%%'"

    echo A new MySQL database has been created for you.
    echo Username: %user%
    echo Password: %password%
    echo Database: %dbname%
    echo Host: %hostinfo%:3306
)
```

I did a similar batch before check this post
http://muhammadhamed.blogspot.com/2013/01/install-mysql-as-windows-service-from.html

I hope this could help!

Comment: Thank you. I actually know where the error is in my script. It is the "SET RESULT" line.
    SET RESULT="mysql -u root -ppassword --skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%dbname%'""

It doesn't accept this because of the quotation marks around "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%dbname%'" - but without them it doesn't work. It works on linux like this:

    RESULT=`mysql -u root -ppassword--skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$dbname'"`

I just need to find a way to have it accept the contents of the line, but I don't know how...

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work. It just said "FALSE was unexpected at this time."
The "SET RESULT=" line doesn't work properly because of the quotations. I've been trying to escape them, but without luck.